# Delphi. REST: Delete an object

Tags: rest, delphi

Loking for some help from Delphi community.

I am working with SynchroTeam API using REST.
[API Documentation here](https://api.synchroteam.com/)

I can successfully GET and POST data without any problem.
But I can't find out the right way to delete a job.
[Delete a Job](https://api.synchroteam.com/#delete-a-job)

After downloading all jobs, I'm trying to delete some of them. So, I know ID, MyID and NUM properties of each Job.
However, when I'm using the following code:

```
RESTClient:= TRESTClient.Create('https://ws.synchroteam.com/api/v3');
with RESTClient do
begin
  Accept:= 'application/json';
  AcceptCharset:= 'UTF-8';
  Authenticator:= HTTPBasicAuthenticator;
  SecureProtocols := [THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS12];
end;
RESTRequest.Method:= TRESTRequestMethod.rmDELETE;
RESTRequest.Resource:= 'job/delete?Myid=467925';
RESTRequest.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json',
                         TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,
                         [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest.AddParameter('Accept', 'text/json',
                         TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,
                         [poDoNotEncode]);   
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

I get the error 404: Job does not exists. I am 100% sur about MyID. I also tried Myid="467925" or with ID property: same result.

If I am trying like this, I get another error: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

```
RESTRequest.Method:= TRESTRequestMethod.rmDELETE;
RESTRequest.Resource:= 'job/delete';
RESTRequest.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json',
                         TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,
                         [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest.AddParameter('Accept', 'text/json',
                         TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,
                         [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest.AddParameter('myId', '467925',
                         TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY,
                         [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

I also tried with TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER for MyId parameter

What would be the correct way to delete a record using REST.Client.TRESTRequest ?

This is the request captured with Fiddler

```
DELETE https://ws.synchroteam.com/api/v3/job/delete?myId=467927 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: text/json
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXX
Cookie: incap_ses_466_1982613=JG+hNrWzP3ntmaXA4pB3BhU0SmAAAAAArMFLFUXF8+BXuhjHFDJEIA==; visid_incap_1982613=eLvuGVc7ToSqZT5dVRPkcRU0SmAAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADEtuE8tUgs/WIAYTcpXzLh; ASP.NET_SessionId=tpffwpqwj0pphbx5s3llzp3f
User-Agent: Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0
Content-Length: 348
Host: ws.synchroteam.com
```

And response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 999
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1615476362
X-Quota-Limit: 15000
X-Quota-Remaining: 14679
Date: Thu, 11 Mar 2021 15:25:02 GMT
Content-Length: 66
X-CDN: Imperva
X-Iinfo: 10-12437416-12437480 SNNN RT(1615476301530 1054) q(0 0 0 -1) r(1 1) U6

{"error":"Not Found","message":"The requested Job does not exist"}
```

According to SynchroTeam support, the payload I'm sending is
(I have removed private data)

```
myId=467927{"id":121464,"firstName":"FFFFF","lastName":NNNNN","login":"LLLLLL","password":"PPPPP","language":"LL","email":"EEEEE","phone":"PPPPPP","profile":"administrator","customFieldValues":[],"skilledTrades":[],"teams":[],"startLocation":{"fullAddress":"","latitude":"","longitude":""},"lastLocation":null,"deleted":""}
```

I don't see where this additional payload with my credentials is defined and why I don't have the same problem with other requests like GET and POST

Comment: The manual says `myId`, not `Myid`.

Comment: Same error with 'job/delete?myId=467925'. Job not found

Comment: The examples have the id value as a URL parameter like `?id=265_160719144323649`. Looks like `TRESTRequest` does not support this for DELETE.

Comment: Same result with     RESTRequest.AddParameter('myId', aJobID, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);

Comment: `myId` is not an HTTP header, so of course `pkHTTPHEADER` will not work. It is a URL query string parameter, so have you tried `pkGETorPOST`, `pkQUERY`, or `pkURLSEGMENT` yet? See [REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Remy. I tried with all of them. With `TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkQUERY` and `TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST`, I get the correct URL with `GetFullRequestURL 'https://ws.synchroteam.com/api/v3/job/delete?Myid=467925'`. But still 404, job not found

Comment: *"I get the correct URL"* Please reread my first comment.

Comment: Sorry Olivier But I reused an old copy/paste here. I am using `myId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my (stupid) mistake.
I still had another object (me as user) as body from another request.
I corrected that using

```
RESTRequest.Body.ClearBody;
RESTRequest.Params.Clear;
```

Case closed